# Magento CE - check if patches have been installed

Tags: magento-1.7

How can I determine if Magento CE 1.7 patches have been installed on my system?

I'm interested in both security patches and the one relating to api changes.

Comment: I think this link will be helpful http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html

Answer (score 2):

**Simply use SSH to check if your shop is patched**

> You can scan your site with magereport.com to see if a patch is installed or not. If a check comes up grey it’s possible the files that are needed for the check are relocated. Therefore it can’t see whether your shop is patched or not. No worries. Simply use SSH to check if your shop is patched.
>
> Every check that’s been installed can easily be found in the content of your shop. More specifically it’s logged in **app/etc/applied.patches.list**
>
> So you run this command **'grep'** on SSH to access the list of applied security patches:

```
grep '|' app/etc/applied.patches.list
```

> The output will look like this:

```
-e 2015-04-14 08:34:22 UTC | SUPEE-5344 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1 | a5c9abcb6a387aabd6b33ebcb79f6b7a97bbde77 | Thu Feb 5 19:14:49 2015 +0200 | v1.14.1.0..HEAD
```

> For More information kindly visit below URL:-
> https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-apply-magento-patches/
>
> Hope It's helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Applying SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-1533 Magento patches via FTP/sFTP or FileManager / File Upload without SSH

Refer Link: http://magentary.com/kb/apply-supee-5344-and-supee-1533-without-ssh/

You can test whether Magento is safe from vulnerable for security point of view or check if patches have been installed see link: https://shoplift.byte.nl/ and enter your URL.

Answer (score 0):

Magento offers a new and free tool to scan shops for security issues. Go to the [Magento Security Scan](https://account.magento.com/scanner) - you have to log in with your account to use this service.

> Monitor your sites for security risks, update malware patches, and detect unauthorized access with Magento Security Scan, the latest FREE tool from Magento Commerce.

You can even setup an automatic scanning schedule (daily or weekly). This way you are notified about known security issues.